# How to fix generic TypeScript function to return valid inferred type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have below TypeScript code ([link to playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noStrictGenericChecks=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=32&pc=72#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-MNc3KP1gSjo2x2ch2c057O7FByRTN1uULzAKn6uxm+Q9ugU-hvIRQXxQFkQAC0mApaOwAwYDBJXDQHke+AAyiuKaxsGYmMBBWYpP2hEA)):

```js
type MyCallback<T> = (s: string, payload: T) => void;

interface IActions {
  do1: MyCallback<number>;
  do2: MyCallback<string>;
  [key: string]: (s: string, payload: any) => void;
}

function convert<T extends { [key: string]: (s: string, payload: any) => void }>(callbackMap: T) {

  const result: { [key: string]: <U>(payload: U) => void } = {};

  Object.keys(callbackMap).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof callbackMap[key] === 'function') {
      result[key] = callbackMap[key].bind(null, "data");
    }
  })

  return result;
}

const maps = convert<IActions>({
  do1: (s: string, payload: number) => {
    //
  },
  do2(s: string, payload: string) {
    //
  }
});

maps.do1(1); // valid
maps.smth("1"); // should be type-check error, but TS thinks it's valid
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a function, which accepts an object via an interface. The function converts all methods from the object to a new object, where all methods have one fixed parameter (via `bind` method). In other words, I want to convert this interface

```js
interface IActions {
  do1: (state: string, payload: number);
  do2: (state: string, payload: string);
  .....
}
```

to

```js
interface IActions {
  do1: (payload: number);
  do2: (payload: string);
  ....
}
```

I want to make it generic, so it converts any interface based on generic parameter.

The issue with my current approach is that I don't have any intellisense and type checking for my `maps` object.

Is it possible to modify my `convert` function in such a way, that return type is automatically inferred by the incoming interface? In other words, I have full type checking and intellisense for return value (`maps` in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `maps.smth` is valid is due to the explicit index signature on the result. What you need here is a mapped type to map over the properties of `IActions` to a new type containing the modified methods. To create the new method signature we can use a conditional type to extract the rest of the parameters (skip the first one)

```
type MyCallback<T> = (s: string, payload: T) => void;

interface IActions {
  do1: MyCallback<number>;
  do2: MyCallback<string>;
}

function convert<T extends Record<keyof T, (s: string, payload: any) => void>>(callbackMap: T) {

  const result: Record<string, (...a: any[]) => any> = {}

  Object.keys(callbackMap).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof callbackMap[key as keyof T] === 'function') {
      result[key] = callbackMap[key as keyof T].bind(null, "data");
    }
  })

  return result as {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (s: string, ...p: infer P) => infer R ? (...p: P) => R : never;
  };
}

const maps = convert<IActions>({
  do1: (s: string, payload: number) => {
    //
  },
  do2(s: string, payload: string) {
    //
  }
});

maps.do1(1); // valid
maps.do1("1"); //err
maps.smth("1"); // should be type-check error, but TS thinks it's valid
```

[Play](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noStrictGenericChecks=true#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-IqrsOvk16n6gYj7r50oLxgBRN8Py-OgkX4PYhCgXwoDxCAAFpMCRKpsAKBgGDhLg0A8at8AAZXgpFWGwMwmGAekzDvZA5CAA)

Comment: WOW, thank you! I've also tried with conditional types and `infer`, but haven't ended up with something workable. It's still advanced for me. 
Could you suggest how to fix the last issue in your playground - TS complaints `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Record<keyof T, (s: string, payload: any) => void>'.` [image](https://www.screencast.com/t/tw7Cdx45J7iE)

Comment: just WOW. Thank you once again, and btw thank you for everything you do in TS area! Today I learned a lot of new things about TS :). Very interesting video about conditional types.